# Anyway to disable "Confirm Form Resubmission" on Google Chrome?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, browser, confirm, submission

Chrome is my browser of choice for web development. Whenever I reload a page that has a form using "Post" I get a "Confirm Form Resubmission" pop-up. This is extremely time consuming over the course of a day.

Is there any known way to disable this? I've searched for an answer but have only found posts from 2010-2011 with no relevant information.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this too old issues but I got the solution... I was getting too this error from chrome confirm form resubmission back button.. "pop up"I follow this tip enter it's working for me...

1. Changing Chrome properties
2. Switching POST method
3. Cripple the motion sensor functionality
4. Evident the Chrome browser data
5. Full reset them
   [You can follow the tips from here](https://www.skytechosting.com/confirm-page-resubmission/)

Comment: Please don't rely on links for the bulk of your answers content. Links can go dead, or the information on the other end can be changed to no longer answer the question. Use links as a source of citation or further reading. Without the link in your answer, the rest of the explanation is not nearly detailed enough to answer the question.

Comment: Your only other post on SE is an [answer on Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com/a/1133178), which also links to the same site you do here. Are you affiliated with this site in some way? SE requires that you disclose any affiliation in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).